# How does a computer evaluates the color code?

Tags: colors

I just want to know that how does a computer know that the value rgb(255, 0, 0) is red or how does it know that a particular color code is for a particular color?

What I want to say is that how computer know that
red means red,
green means green,
white means white,
blue means blue so on.

Please explain it without taking an analogy. I want to know the real thing happening behind the hood.

Comment: this may help https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs101/image-1-introduction.html

Comment: What do you mean? You mean how the computer knows that a 255, 0, 0 means "red" and 10, 10, 10 means a "very dark gray" or what?

Comment: Because if that's what you're asking this has very little to do with programming and more to do with [color theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory), specifically [additive color mixing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_color)

Comment: [Let’s do Colormath](https://donatbalipapp.medium.com/colours-maths-90346fb5abda).

Comment: That's basically just a map: the key "red is mapped to rgb(255,0,), "green" to rgb (0, 255, 0) etc. - It's the RGB value or maybe some other color space that value is converted to which is used to generate the monitor image, print papers etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your computer doesn't need to "know" anything about what a color "means", it just has to pass the numeric values of the R, G, and B components of a color value to your monitor, which is wired up to emit corresponding levels of red, green, and blue light. (That's oversimplifying a bit, because all sorts of color processing might go on first, but that's still the gist of it.)

Different levels of those different colors, when mixed together, produce the wide gamut of colors that your monitor can produce, and from there, it's a matter of how your brain processes that mix of primary colors that determines what colors you see.

Answer (score 0):

The computer doesn't know the meaning of red (nor the meaning of the letter A).

Computer get the data (255, 0, 0) and it put it in memory, telling that pixel X has such values. Really graphic libraries handle the position of the pixel, knowing the coordinates, and also knowing the colour deep, now often we have 32-bits per pixels, with a consistent pattern.

Video card will read the memory, interpret it and convert to a standardized signal (e.g. HDMI, SRGB, 8bit per channel, progressive, 4:4:4 colour configuration, screen-size AxB, data speed, etc.), and it will send it to the screen. If screen can interpret such data flow, it will send it to the pannel, and pannel will *illuminate* the pixel (often it will just allow the backlight to pass thru it, with a specific intensity). A colour filter is applied over every pixel so you get (your eyes) a specific colour. If you displace the colour filter, there is no way computer, video card, screen, and panel will know about you are seeing different colours).

So: computer handle just numbers. Libraries and computer languages handle the interface *user* (or better programmer) to data, so that you can write "red" in CSS, or #FF0000 in HTML, or 255,0,0. Then one ore more libraries (e.g. moving windows, transparency) will handle data, having some information about structure (system setting for your screen). Video cards, screens, and pannels will know very few about the meaning of data.

Note: operating systems, video cards, and screens may change the meaning of the colours. It is usually done in colour profiles, to get better colours according hardware, but there are also test ICC files which just invert colours (or used for high contrast, or colour blind people). In such case computer have no idea that "red" will be displayed as "black" (as an example).

You should always think as "sandwich": semantic (so real meaning) should be known only on first input and last output. For the rest, computers is just working with numbers (and they may not know anything about semantic). Sorry for the unwanted analogy.